# Mix globbing and wildcards when specifying rule input

Tags: snakemake

Consider the following scenario.

```
├── sample-alice
│   ├── sequence_1.fastq
│   ├── sequence_2.fastq
│   ├── ...
│   └── sequence_n.fastq
└── sample-bob
    ├── sequence_1.fastq
    ├── sequence_2.fastq
    ├── ...
    └── sequence_m.fastq
```

I'm trying to write a single rule in my Snakefile that will preprocess each sample generically. The rule will execute a single command that takes all of Fastq files associated with the sample simultaneously. The samples do not have the same number of Fastq files.

If it was a single sample, I could do something like this.

```py
rule preprocess:
    input: glob('sample-alice/*.fastq')
    output: 'alice-clean.fastq'
    shell: 'mypreproccmd {input} > {output}'
```

On the other hand, if there was a single Fastq file for each sample, I could use a wildcard to write a generic rule like this.

```py
rule preprocess:
    input: 'sample-{samp}/sequence_1.fastq'
    output: '{samp}-clean.fastq'
    shell: 'mypreproccmd {input} > {output}'
```

Is it possible to combine these two approaches to write a rule for handling multi-file samples generically?

Comment: I'm not sure if this exactly solves your question, but in one of my workflows I use the directory as input (as specified in the config.yaml). The shell command then uses {input}/*.fastq.gz See some examples here: https://github.com/wdecoster/nano-snakemake/blob/master/rules/align.smk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice solution comes from a colleague of mine, as seen in [this Snakemake workflow](https://github.com/AlexanderLabWHOI/tara-euk-metaG/blob/ef0f140b7d79540da22da48d4b8e939b95e21f0b/Snakefile#L150-L172). The trick is to access the wildcards programmatically using an anonymous (lambda) function. In my example above, it would be implemented as follows.

```py
from glob import glob

rule preprocess:
    input: lambda wildcards: glob('sample-{samp}/*.fastq'.format(samp=wildcards.samp))
    output: '{samp}-clean.fastq'
    shell: 'mypreproccmd {input} > {output}'
```

Comment: Note that your `Snakefile` needs a `from glob import glob` for this to work

Comment: And it's a bit more succinct using fstrings: `glob(f'sample-{wildcards.samp}/*.fastq')`